# Does IMDF supersede DynamicsPerf for performance monitoring?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I need to troubleshoot poor performance issues in Dynamics 2012.  Per [TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149695.aspx), it lists four options, here are two of them:

> • Performance Analyzer for Microsoft Dynamics AX (DynamicsPerf) – DynamicsPerf can be used to collect information from Microsoft Dynamics AX and SQL Server. DynamicsPerf consists of a database and a collection of scripts that collect information from SQL Server and Microsoft Dynamics AX. Based on this information, you can find issues such as expensive queries and locking/blocking. When you have gained experience, you can also use this tool to find inefficient code or business processes.
>
> • Intelligent Data Management Framework for Microsoft Dynamics AX –Intelligent Data Management Framework (IDMF) provides functionality that resembles the functionality of DynamicsPerf, and also includes a user interface. IDMF also provides tools for activities that are related to data management, such as archiving and purging.

DynamicsPerf is what PFEs/Support teams use, while IDMF sounds like the same thing, but with a GUI.

Does IDMF supercede DyanmicsPerf?  I cannot figure out which one I should be using.